# Javascript drawing library?

Tags: javascript, graphics

Any suggestion for a JavaScript interactive drawing library? Just need to draw lines, polygons, texts of different colors. IE/Firefox/Opera/Safari compatible.
­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 47):

[Raphael](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) is pretty cool for that, and works across browsers since it uses VML (for MSIE) and SVG (for everything else).

Comment: Damn, you beat me to the punch ;)

Comment: THANKS heaps this looks super awesome. will be using Raphael.

Answer (score 15):

John Resig's [Processing.js](http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/) is a nice framework for that.

Comment: how does processing.js compare with raphael for static graphics?

Comment: Sadly Processing does not support IE. Thats a bit of a pity, it looks great though.

Comment: Looks like IE is now supported (IE9)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the canvas object directly to draw in 2D.  IE requires the excanvas library.

http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

Comment: Canvas is the way to go for anything more than a few trivial boxes or lines. And excanvas works surprisingly well, at least on IE 7.

Comment: looks like Raphael can do more than simple boxes and lines.. http://raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 3):

Try http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm.  It's the best I've found (without resorting to SVG) and works in most browsers without add-ins.

Comment: That stuff (drawing by arranging HTML elements) doesn't scale particularly well, but it certainly works :)

Comment: True ... you certainly wouldn't build a CAD system this way, but it can do pretty complex drawings if you stick with orthogonal structures and images (lines, rectangles, etc) and spice them up a bit with images.  Other drawing entities are built with multiple DIV elements each.

Comment: walterzorn.com doesn't seem to be around any more. :(

Comment: new url: http://www.c-point.com/javascript_vector_draw.htm

Answer (score 2):

Drawing text with the canvas tag is a big pain. Your options are to use regular divs absolutely positioned in the right places, or find/write a font layout engine ([example](http://www.federated.com/%7Ejim/canvastext/)), or wait for a new standard to be implemented that lets you draw text. SVG deals with this much better.

In IE you have [ExplorerCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) to simulate the canvas API with IE's own VML markup. However, native VML can do text on a path and such things much like SVG. I think theoretically if you want complex text handling you'd want SVG and VML like the Raphael library that Dan mentioned.

You might also consider Flash for a moment before starting.

Comment: In fact, VML supports text drawing natively, and the latest revisions of ExplorerCanvas have the text drawing methods recommended by the WHATWG  ;)
http://explorercanvas.blogspot.com/

Comment: Just as an update. Text is much less of a pain now(2011), it's been pretty good for the last year. iOS4.1+ finally supports text on canvases correctly and I know Android 2.1+ does as well. Firefox/Safari/Chrome always have had good canvas text support and IE9+ also does text in Canvas correctly.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, canvas is the way you should go. IE doesn't support it natively, so you'll need to download [ExCanvas](http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) to ensure cross-browser compatibility. I'd recommend looking at [Ajaxian](http://ajaxian.com/by/topic/canvas) for some projects that use the canvas tag.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [jQuery Drawing plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Draw), and you can also look at the Mozilla [Canvas](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas) reference and [tutorial](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

Also [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html). This doesn't use excanvas for IE. Excanvas is way slower than using VML, specifically, re-using the same VML nodes rather than deleting, adding DOM nodes for redrawing. This is often a overlooked point, but excanvas on IE performance is just awful.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how cross-browser you need to be and your goal of doing the output, you might look into the Canvas element and the related javascript.

[Canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_(HTML_element))

Answer (score 0):

[D3.js](http://d3js.org/)

> D3.js is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on
>   data. D3 helps you bring data to life using HTML, SVG, and CSS. D3’s
>   emphasis on web standards gives you the full capabilities of modern
>   browsers without tying yourself to a proprietary framework, combining
>   powerful visualization components and a data-driven approach to DOM
>   manipulation.

Take a look at this [discussion](http://www.slant.co/topics/28/~what-are-the-best-javascript-drawing-libraries) too.