# Best javascript framework for drawing/showing images?

Tags: javascript, toolkit

What's the best javascript framework for drawing (lines, curves whatnot) on images?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery has several plugins available for doing graphics.  Raphael is a plugin that uses SVG (for Firefox and other browsers that support SVG), and VML for the IE products.  In addition, jQuery provides a great architecture for javascript projects with plenty of support and plug-ins.

Raphael is available here: http://raphaeljs.com/index.html

jQuery is available here: http://jquery.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Processing](http://ejohn.org/blog/processingjs/)

```
var p = Processing(CanvasElement);
p.size(100, 100);
p.background(0);
p.fill(255);
p.ellipse(50, 50, 50, 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this library that is a jquery plugin:
http://www.openstudio.fr/Library-for-simple-drawing-with.html

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96486/javascript-drawing-library#96509).

Answer (score 0):

You can create "images" using javascript's flot library.

It's on [google code: flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/)
And requires [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/)

Here's an example, how a [graph might look like](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html)