# Can somebody tell me good 2d library for JavaScript if exists?

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework

I want to write chess in JavaScript  but I am pretty new to JavaScript. Can somebody tell me good 2d library for JavaScript if exists ? Is there possible to write 3d objects with JavaScript ? Any advice is helpful

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript drawing library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96486/javascript-drawing-library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) and [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/).

The [processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference) lists a few 3d primitives so you can render 3d objects, at least in a limited manner.

Answer (score 1):

Re: 3D objects in JS, Check out [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) for an *excellent* 3d library.  It supports WebGL, Canvas, SVG rendering (WebGL being **significantly** faster in browser that support it).

Get a new browser if necessary (e.g. chrome dev build) and check out some of the webgl demos.