# Draw and save graphics

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to make a small application in asp.net where user could draw a small drawing and that drawing is saved in the database for later review.

I have no idea where to begin from.  Could you give me a hint please?
Thanks

Comment: if you mean that the user need to draw on the browser, then you first need to ask for javascript, and check for the "canvas".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for [System.Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) to draw in ASP.net but it is not much supported.. to get more information check this [System.Drawing in Windows or ASP.NET services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390532/system-drawing-in-windows-or-asp-net-services)

> Check this interesting stuff regarding ASP.Net that may help you:
>
> [Build Flexible, Lightweight XML-Based Images for ASP.NET Using
>   Scalable Vector Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164114.aspx)

Check libraries specified on Stackoverflow question
[Javascript drawing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96486/javascript-drawing-library)

Check these links:
http://www.p01.org/releases/Drawing_lines_in_JavaScript/
[10 Best Javascript Drawing and Canvas Libraries](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.Drawing` for creating image (lots of tutorials online).

Then you can save image to DB (SQL Express, MySQL?) or maybe better save it to disc with some generated filename and save only path to DB. If you don't know how to access DB then you should first choose one. I recommend [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx).

Comment: Thanks ! I need to draw in a browser (online drawing) and then save to sql server database........