# Tree with 2 parents: Build a family tree HTML/javascript as familyecho do

Tags: html, family-tree

I want to display a genealogy tree without flash. In HTML/javascript/css.

I have a big problem displaying my tree because of the:

- Difficulty to display the marital link between 2 parents
- the children nodes

Do you know any api which can build a family tree as www.familyecho.com does? I am gonna be crazy????

Here an example

```
 Father --- Mother
         |
|--------|------------|
Child1   Child2     Child3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may want to take a look at http://www.myheritage.nl as example, familiecho is pale in comparison to that. Is free for op to 500 familimembers but unfortunatly is made in Flash, so no chance of borrowing some code or libraries there.

If you just want to use HTML there is http://www.starkeffect.com/ged2html/ but is a bit oldfashioned.

There are several drawing libraries for javascript bun none that are aimed at genealogy as far as i know, anyone who comes up with one i would be gratefull.
Raphael at http://raphaeljs.com/ being the widest known vector graphics library, see http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/drawing/10-best-javascript-drawing-and-canvas-libraries/ for a comparison and see this [Javascript drawing library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96486/javascript-drawing-library) question. Basically you will have to make a choice between vector (eg SVG) approach and rendered graphics (eg Canvas), each of them having their own advantages, libraries and followers.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.outten.org/?id=46

Based largely on the familyecho look which I also liked.

Data is dynamic from MySQL & the dragable page gfx are built locally in javascript. A bit hashed together with tables, but works in a fashion except on mobile devices.

Alex

Comment: Alex theres very little info on how the person should approach the problem. Just an example of something that worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an API as Familyecho. There is already an API supported by Familyecho.com You can use it, they also provide developer sample code for quick integration. Navigate to their website for more info.

> Here is the link: https://www.familyecho.com/?page=api

Answer (score -1):

Wes, the link was to a page that has the code embedded, not just example of output.
The data is pulled from MySQL translated into a js object (here:https://www.outten.org/data.php?id=46).

Else the javascript is self explanatory at the bottom of the document source, otherwise standard JS jQuery etc. used.
There's no licensing for this code only what has been used from others & may be used as you wish. There are many things that could be improved about it.

BTW the link has changed & been updated to:
https://www.outten.org/newTree.html?id=46

I had been looking for a JS module to do this for decades, but none do even Node.js

With regards

Xander (Alex) Lost old stack exchange login :(