# Store user's drawing with javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, paperjs, pixi.js

I need to store a path drawn by user, along with the speed at any given point. Basically record how a line is drawn. I must be able to manipulate/edit the drawing (path and speed) afterwards.

Something like this but also with speed/velocity information:

http://paperjs.org/examples/path-simplification

I wonder how should I store the speed? Is there better way than store pointer place for example 10 times a second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in your own custom-made object. Make an event listener that listens to every `mousemove` event after it's been clicked:

```
var pointArray = [];

onMouseMove(event){
    var pointData = {
        x: event.screenX,
        y: event.screenY,
        time: Date.now()
    }

    pointArray.push(pointData);
}
```

Now you have a long `pointArray` full of position & time information! By the way, there is no point in storing data 10 times per second because you'll only get redundant information if the mouse isn't moving. It's better to simply listen for `mousemove`.

Comment: Makes sense. I will think about this.

Comment: Why use the Date object when all mouse events have a high resolution timestamp. `event.timeStamp` in millisecond accurate to 1 microsecond

Comment: I just tested your method in FFox, and I got 124 `console.logs` that read `18446744072697221000` before the value changed. `Date.now()` has better results.

Comment: @Blindman67 How would you use that high resolution time stamp? The DOM timers are operating with milliseconds only, you can't "replay" the record with hires timestamps.

Comment: @Teemu A good mouse can fire move events in less than a ms. Timers are not the only way to set state according to time.  And there are a zillion ways that a hires timestamp is better than low res

Comment: @Blindman67 You didn't answer the question. How would you use that high resolution timestamp? `requestAnimationFrame()` caps at 60fps, and `setTimeout()` caps out at 1ms...

Comment: @MarcoDelValle You miss the point The timestamp is the time of the event, not the time the event listener was called, which can be tens of milliseconds after the event depending on what code is running. Javascript is blocking, event listeners will not be called until current execution is complete and all other events that came befor have been executed. The high resolution timeStamp is just a bonus

Comment: @Blindman67 Eh, OP wants to emulate user's drawing speed. You can store the timestamps when recording a draw, but there's no use for it when "playing" the record. There simply is no way in JS to call drawing functions faster than about 1 - 10 msecs. hence using hires timestamp for the record would be overkilling.

Comment: @Teemu If you are recording the mouse position for playback and use Date your record any janking that occurs during the record process. Using timestamp completely eliminates this problem. If you use event time to calculate the mouse speed and use that speed to add brush FX (like simulating ink pens) using the Date the result is awful, but using  timeStamp produces beautifully smooth simulations.

Answer (score 0):

Any line can be represented as a number of **points**. If you store the *timestamp* of each point, you'll be able to infer the average speed between any two points on the line.

[Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/examples/path-simplification/) as you linked above is an interesting example of representing paths in JS. I'd recommend researching existing libraries to create and represent paths in Javascript. In the long run, it will save you time in comparison to writting your own library for the functionality.

Here's a relevant Stack Overflow Answer about differences in Javascript drawing libraries.

- [Javascript Drawing
  Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96486/javascript-drawing-library)

Comment: Timestamps are good idea.! I'm afraid average speed is not enough so that might not work. Anyway I will investigate that approach further...